# install a node js package from tar

Tags: node.js, tar, npm-install

I have created a tar file from my entire package directory including the package file and try to use the command

```
npm install package.tar
```

from my projects folder where the tar file is, however I am getting an error that says:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projects\package.json'
```

If I try to put the package.json file in projects folder, I get:

```
Refusing to install package as a dependency of itself
```

```
C:\Projects>npm install nodeTest.tar
C:\Projects
`-- node-test@1.0.0

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Projects\package.json'
npm WARN Projects No description
npm WARN Projects No repository field.
npm WARN Projects No README data
npm WARN Projects No license field.
```

How exactly do I install a package from a tar file?

I just want to be able to install a package from a file without pulling from published online npm packages

Comment: Is the `ENOENT` an _error_ or a _warning_?

Comment: it is a warning it says but its not installing the package

Comment: Is that the entire output of `npm install package.tar`? No lines before or after that?

Comment: just those couple lines i added above

Comment: It's actually telling you that it got installed just fine (as `node_modules/node-test/`)

Comment: Oh I see, it created a node_modules folder and put my node test in there, however I had a dependency, lodash in the node_modules folder of node_test and it just put it in the node_modules folder under projects instead of creating a node_modules folder in node_test... I was hoping it would keep the file structure and install everything as it was when i zipped it..

Comment: NPM will try to "flatten" the package hierarchy in `node_modules` as much as possible, but that shouldn't be a problem.